# what is the correct usage of tense

Tags: tenses

**I ____ for delhi next week ?**

1 leave

2 have been leaving

3.had left

4 are leaving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really are forced to choose, then 1 is the only possible answer. But it would require the context to be e.g. that his/her leaving is scheduled (present simple can be used to express future if based on timetable, etc.).

However, even number 1 doesn't sound very natural or common. Normally, you would hear something like "I'm leaving" as a future form.

Also, the question with a word order of a statement would suggest surprise or something similar.